# Custom sessions in Ember Js. How to set/access session information

Tags: javascript, session, ember.js, ember-cli

So I followed a youtube tutorial on how authorize using session tokens. The main session code was the following.

```
//app/services/session.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    token: null,
    authenticate(log, pass) {
        return Ember.$.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/token',
            data: {username: log, password: pass}

        }).then((info)=>{
            this.set('token',info.access_token);
        });
    }
});
```

server set over here.

```
//server/index.js

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

    app.post('/token', function(req, res){
        console.log(res);

        if(req.body.username === 'erik' &&
            req.body.password === 'password') {
                res.send( { access_token: 'secretcode'});
            } else {
                res.status(400).send({ error: 'invalid_grant'});
            }


    });

    app.get('/api/students', function(req, res) {

        if( req.headers.authorization !== 'Bearer secretcode'){
            return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
        }

        return res.status(200).send({
            students: [
                { id: 1, name: 'Erik', age: 23},
                { id: 2, name: 'Bob',  age: 52}
            ]
        });



    });
};
```

So how do I set multiple info on the session token. Like the `user_id`? So I give access to a page only if session contains a `user_id` or just using it in controller like

```
click_if_authenticated(){ //use session.user_id here}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to authorize users with [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) library. It gives you a possiblity to check the status of a session if **isAuthenthicaded** and display the content that you need. Moreover it is possible to define routes which require authenticated user and the ones where authentication is not required etc. I think this will be much easier approach for your than the one that you are trying to make.

Comment: The task was to implement it along with pouchdb. At what point do I interact with pouchdb in case of ember-simple-auth? In the guides it uses component-componentjs-service-mock_server to store data. Got any idea on how to approach this problem?